# how to insert alt tag inside anchor tag in php?

Tags: php, html

```
    <div >
        <a href="<?=site_url()?>"><?=img('logo.png',array('class'=>'logo'))?></a>
    </div>
```

I want to add an ALT TAG for logo.png

thanks

Comment: Which PHP Framework are you using ? Code igniter ?

Comment: do you mean alt attribute of img element?

Comment: Where's the alt? Isn't this just a malformed link?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya yes man, codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

If you are using code igniter framework you can do it like this

**From The Codeigniter Documentation**

```
$image_properties = array(
          'src' => 'images/picture.jpg',
          'alt' => 'Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time',
          'class' => 'post_images',
          'width' => '200',
          'height' => '200',
          'title' => 'That was quite a night',
          'rel' => 'lightbox',
);

img($image_properties);
```

[img()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img)

Answer (score 1):

Guess you are using some kind of framework, so the answer could not be correct.
Please, try this:

```
<div>
    <a href="<?=site_url()?>"><?=img('logo.png', array('class'=>'logo', 'alt'=>'Write here your alternative text'))?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: anchor tag does not have alt attribute .

Comment: It's not inside the anchor tag, it's inside some **img()** php function, which is supposed to print an img tag..

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div >
        <a title="your site" href="<?=site_url()?>"><?=img('logo.png',array('class'=>'logo'))?></a>
    </div>
```

You can not use alt attribute in anchor tag, instead use title attribute or , if it is an image as in your case it is a logo . You can use img tag and alt attribute.

may be something like with little bit modification.

```
<a href="<?=site_url()?>"><img src="<?=img('logo.png',array('class'=>'logo'))?>" alt="your site" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

after looking your code,you might be used **"codeigniter"** framework  and below is a solution for your code.below code is showing how to add a attribute in img function.you need to just pass an array,that contain a attribute and there value.

```
<div>
<a href="<?=site_url()?>">
<?= img(array('src'=>'image/logo.png', 
                    'alt'=> 'alt information',
                     'class'=>'logo')); ?>
</a>
</div>
```

please correct your syntax.